# Draw stright line using customPainter in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have Two Offset to draw Line using Custom Painter, i need to check these offsets are in straight line (horizontally). how do i check? If not it is not in a straight line, how to change offset.

Comment: *"how do i check? "* - you want to check if `dy` property is the same for both `Offset`s?

Comment: or if not, what actually do you want to check?

Comment: thanx, i got  solution from your first comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two lines are horizontally straight if they share the same dy property.

To check if they are the same you can do:

```
Offset o1 = ...;
Offset o2 = ...;

if(o1.dy == o2.dy) {
    // horizontal line
}
else {
    // not horizontal
}
```